# SWI-Prolog goal fail variable binding result

Tags: prolog

Is there any way that I can get a binding for a variable in Prolog even if the goal fails. I have a predicate where I am binding a variable with some value and after this I am failing the goal explicitly, but when I run the query it simply results in a fail without providing any biding for the variable. Something similar:

```
a(X) :-
 X = 'something',
 fail.
```

Comment: Do you also have a `a(_).` rule somewhere in your code? It looks like you're trying to force backtracking with `fail`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, this is how it is supposed to happen in Prolog. `fail` means the rejection of bindings made so far, because it says that these bindings are invalid, do not satisfy the goal.

but you can save some binding that will be undone on backtracking, with e.g. [`asserta` predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=asserta/1):

```
a(X) :-
 X = 'something',
 asserta(saved_x(X)),
 fail.
```

Then, if you query `saved_x(Z)` afterwards, you will recover that value. Of course this is the part of Prolog that is *extra*-logical, i.e. *outside* of the logical programming paradigm.

Comment: Global state and `assert` are so un-Prolog-ish, though... I think the OP should explain what he's trying to do, otherwise it's going to be hard to come up with a proper solution.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight couldn't agree more.

Comment: Facts asserted to the DB using `asserta/1` during execution aren't retracted on backtracking... they produce side effects! Nevertheless, they can indeed be used to capture intermediate state like you've shown (+1).

Comment: @sharky yes, I thought that is what I said. :) *bindings* are retracted, so we save them with `assert` (if we *must*). .... changed some wording, thanks.

Comment: I'd say that bindings are _lost_ on backtracking, and that asserted facts using `assert/1` are _not retracted_ on backtracking. There's a distinct difference!

Comment: Yep, I think 'undone' is more appropriate. Nice answer. I'd done something along these lines a long time ago (though I can't remember what for), but you can even capture the local variable name used, predicate, clause reference and other facts to assert to `saved_x` which could be helpful using this method.

Comment: @sharky better call Prolog "pl", mentally, when you're forced to use it in such fashion. ;) :) what's nice to "pl", is to Prolog ... *not attractive*. :) e.g. the solution in your answer is what I'd call "nice" (Prolog-wise).

Answer (score 3):

@Will Ness is correct (+1), `assert` can be used to capture bindings of variables as shown.

However, if you *strictly* need to retrieve bindings for variables in predicates like `a` and you *know* which parts could fail (and you *don't care about them*), then you could  use combinations of cut (`!`) and `true` to permit `a` to proceed regardless. For example, consider:

```
a(X) :-
    goalA(X), % a goal for which we definitely want a binding
    (goalB, ! ; true). % an 'optional' goal which may fail

goalA('something').
goalB :- fail.
```

Executing this gives `a('something')`, even though `goalB` failed. Note that this isn't a commonly used way to program in Prolog, but if you know exactly what you're doing...